# LEFT JOIN with EXTRA INFORMATION

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables

table1: **households**

| Serial_no | Address |
| --- | --- |
| sn1 | New York |
| sn2 | Maryland |
| sn3 | France |

table2: **citizens**

| Serial_id | Fullname | Role | household_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Head | sn1 |
| 2 | Jane | Spouse | sn1 |
| 3 | Johny | Son | sn1 |
| 4 | Mike | Head | sn2 |

I want the output to be like this:

| Serial_no | Address | Total_count | Head |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sn1 | New York | 3 | John |
| sn2 | Maryland | 1 | Mike |
| sn3 | France | 0 | *null* |

I'm stuck here. please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why john for sn1??

Comment: Hi! if you are referring to the expected output, it's because John's role is the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `group by` like below:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table households(Serial_no varchar(10),    Address varchar(50));

 insert into households values('sn1',            'New York');
 insert into households values('sn2',            'Maryland');
 insert into households values('sn3',            'France');

 create table citizens(Serial_id int, Fullname varchar(50), Role varchar(10), household_id varchar(10));

 insert into citizens values(1,'John', 'Head',    'sn1');
 insert into citizens values(2,'Jane', 'Spouse', 'sn1');
 insert into citizens values(3,'Johny', 'Son',       'sn1');
 insert into citizens values(4,'Mike', 'Head',     'sn2');
```

Query:

```
 select Serial_no,Address,count(c.household_id) Total_count,
 max(case when Role='Head' then Fullname end) Head
 from households h
 left join citizens c
           on h.Serial_no=c.household_id
 group by Serial_no,Address
```

Output:

| Serial_no | Address | Total_count | Head |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sn1 | New York | 3 | John |
| sn2 | Maryland | 1 | Mike |
| sn3 | France | 0 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=be385df438ba1efd46dfa21e4f006a50)*

Comment: Thanks bro. Your code works perfect on the example that I have given.  Thank you very much! You're a life saver

Comment: You are most welcome. If it helped you please accept the answer by clicking the green check so this question can be marked as answered. Best wishes.

Comment: sorry bro. TBH I'm not really 100% familiar with github. Thanks again!

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes.